# Python import ignores __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I name my modules same as class names. So `MyClass.py` would contain `class MyClass`.
(Why? I adopted this naming convention from other languages and would rather not change it)
I put it in directory `components` with `__init__.py` like this:

```
from .MyClass1 import MyClass1
from .MyClass2 import MyClass2
```

I do exactly the same thing for classes in directory `controllers`.

Then, in my `main.py`, I try to import them like so:

```
from components import MyClass1, MyClass2
from controllers import MyClass3, MyClass4
```

From `components` it imports fine, from `controllers`, it ignores my `__init__.py` and imports a module instead of class, so I have to rewrite my imports like so:

```
from components import MyClass1, MyClass2
from controllers.MyClass3 import MyClass3
from controllers.MyClass4 import MyClass4
```

Please tell me what could be the reason? Is there a way to fix this without having to change naming convention? Thank you.

Comment: You are in a problem of your own making. You shouldn't name your modules the same as your classnames. For many reasons, but importantly because you can't use the same name twice in a single namespace. Try following common Python naming conventions and name your modules `my_class1` and `my_class2` if you like the idea of naming them the same as your classes (I assume because each module only contains the code for each class).

Comment: *Why* are you naming your modules and classes the same thing, and defining just one class per module? That's a bit of nonsense Java imposes, but it's not how Python is supposed to work at all. It's also violating PEP8 naming conventions (modules should be named in `lowercase` or `lower_case_with_underscores`, classes named in `CapWords` style).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I find it clear and useful when I find cookies in a jar with a label "cookies". Not cookies and rasins, and not cake. It does not seem a bit nonsensical to me

Comment: @LexPodgorny: Except you're denamespacing things, so the bonus labels aren't actually involved in any sense but making extra layers in your directory layout. Without the denamespacing, you'd be putting your cookies in cookie jar labeled cookies, that you put inside a larger cookie jar also labeled cookies. And it breaks down completely for stuff that isn't classes anyway; do you put every global constant and every function in a separate module of the same name? Or are you writing purely class-based code, as if this is Java and it's not legal to write code outside of classes?

Comment: To be clear, "I adopted this naming convention from other languages and would rather not change it" is not a justification. You're not writing Java anymore. Sticking to conventions of some other language *that violate the conventions of the language you're actually writing* is just being stubborn for the sake of being stubborn, and it makes you actively disruptive if you're ever coding in a team that adheres to the language's actual conventions.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Not sure what Java did to you, but I've never written Java. But I do like clear class encapsulation, it makes code clear-purposed and organised, especially when writing framework-level code. I do like Python, but sometimes I don't agree how opinionated it gets. I believe, naming conventions should be left to a coder's decision.

Comment: And most definitely, language should not just break because of my choice of case.